# Не пишутся русские буквы при сохранении в базу данных

Tags: java, mysql, база-данных, spring-boot

**Цель**: сохранить данные в БД MySQL.

**Проблема**: при отправке данных, сохраняются разные неизвестные символы. Понимаю, что дело в кодировке, но совершенно не понимаю как ещё изменить нужно. Пишу "Привет", а сохраняет "%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%8B".

**Ошибка**:  `java.sql.SQLException: Unsupported character encoding 'UTF8MB4'`

**Файл** `application.properties`

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testing?useUnicode=true&character_set_server=utf8mb4&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>


    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
        <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>ApiConnect</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ApiConnect</name>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mustache</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>

            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: для MySQL кодировка бд должна быть UTF8MB4

Comment: @Дмитрий , спасибо, я поставил кодировку, а он ошибку выдаёт, добавил немного кода, можете посмотреть?

Comment: у вас не установлен диалект. я не знаю, какая у вас версия MySQL, посему для 5 будет примерно так hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect, а для 8 так hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect

Comment: Ошибка осталась прежняя, пробовал два варианта, на сайте написано: MySQL 8.0 Server

Comment: спринг используете? покажите весь файл application.properties

Comment: spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://db4free.net/testingerapi?useUnicode=true&serverTimezone=UTC&characterEncoding=UTF8MB4&useSSL=true&verifyServerCertificate=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=password

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

Comment: примерно так должен выглядеть файл свойств

Comment: Добавил в описание pom и полный prop. Попробовал ваш вариант,  но всё равно не сработало, конкретной ошибки нет, но в одном моменте это заметил: java.sql.SQLException: Unsupported character encoding 'UTF8MB4'

Comment: вряд ли ваша база данных поменяла кодировку только потому , что вы указали в урле новую кодировку. проверьте это руками. можно, например, через workbench, там же, кстати, можно попробовать и изменить кодировку в текущей базе

Comment: "спасибо, я поставил кодировку, а он ошибку выдаёт" - @Balcit, приведите ошибку

Comment: Добавил текст из консоли, вопрос был про Spring, да, его использую. Посмотрел на сайте какая кодировка - utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci.

Comment: @Blacit так не работает. при создании бд в MySQL сделали немного "кривую" кодировку UTF-8, посему при попытке сохранить какой-то спец,символ все валилось. тогда была добавлена кодировка UTF8MB4, которая призвана устранить данную проблему.но это никак не влияет на вашу универсальную ОРМ, ведь ОРМ должна работать универсальным способом с множеством бд, а UTF8MB4 - костыль MySQL. поэтому в урле это указывать не надо. вы работаете на уровне бекенда с обычной UTF8, однако при создании бд в MySQL следует указать для сharset UTF8MB4 и для collation general_ci. полагаю, теперь будет понятнее

Comment: Я так и выбираю, стоит UTF8MB4 и выбрал UTF8MB4_general_ci. В файле prop прописано так, как вы сказали. Он пишет вот это: 'java.sql.SQLException: Unsupported character encoding 'UTF8MB4'
 at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
 at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]'

Comment: Может, encode применяется дважды, а decode - только один раз? :-)

Comment: @Blacit , решили ли Вы эту проблему с MySQL? Интересно, т.к. у меня такая же проблема в spring boot приложении: при попытке добавить в application.properties к url characterEncoding=UTF8MB4 валится с такой же эксепшн.

Comment: Пока что не решил, сегодня буду ставить себе MySQL на компьютер, может, это конкретно ошибка на сайте в кодировке. Я честно не знаю и буду стараться разбираться, ибо из-за этого у меня весь процесс стоит.

Comment: У меня так выглядит prop и не пишет русские символы, также ещё какие-то. Консоль вообще идеально выглядит, никаких ошибок. `spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testing?useUnicode=true&serverTimezone=UTC&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useSSL=true&verifyServerCertificate=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update`Какие варианты только не пытался использовать, абсолютно ничего не помогает, может, pom не такой?

Comment: @Blacit , я задал вопрос на другой площадке (тут: https://vk.com/feed?w=wall-46335054_7838_r7850 ). Результата пока нет. Но можете тоже следить.   Вдруг там появится решение.

Comment: Проблема стала ещё интереснее, исправил все ошибки, которые только появлялись, но всё равно ничего не получается, топик обновил.

Comment: @Дмитрий Пожалуйста, сделайте здесь ответ про hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect и отмечу его правильным, он помог избавиться от ошибки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

у вас не установлен диалект. я не знаю, какая у вас версия MySQL, посему для 5 будет примерно так

```
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

для 8 так

```
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
```